Ubuntu 22.04 openssl.cnf missing - create new default?
my openssl.cnf went missing.
Is it possible to generate a new default one?

When the system complains it is missing I would try
touch /path/to/file/openssl.cnf
If that doesnt work reinstall and overwrite custom changes

Although in some cases configuration files are generated on-the-fly by package installation scripts, in this case a default file is provided as part of the package contents - as you can verify using a dpkg search:
$ dpkg -S /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl: /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

So you can obtain a copy by downloading the deb file and extracting it, ex.
apt download openssl

(which downloads to the local directory - so no special privileges required) then
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18_amd64.deb | tar xf - ./etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

You can then copy the file to its rightful place:
sudo cp ./etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/

You can delete the downloaded deb file and fsys-tarfile tree after.
